# Not able to hit azure function in local running from vs code in java

Tags: java, azure, maven, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am facing issue while calling an azure function developed in java with VS Code. Everything goes fine except the run command. When I run the command 'mvn azure-functions:run', it starts properly. But I am not able to hit it from postman. Here is my code.

```
public class Function {
    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage hello(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"get", "post"}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage req,
                       final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP triger processed a request.");

        String query = req.getQueryParameters().get("name").toString();

        return req.createResponse(200, "hELLO "+query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a try of the code in my answer. And please have a look of the offcial template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=java#example

Comment: Hi, any update? can you work it out now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Thank's for Satya Panigrahy's sharing, the solution is to run mvn generate to generate azure function. By the way, azure function tools dont have a template of java language. For more information, please have a look of this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-kotlin-maven?tabs=cmd#generate-a-new-functions-project

**Original Answer:**

Please have a look of this offcial template:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=java#example

I think the `HttpRequestMessage` dont have a method named `createResponse`. If you want to achieve, please have a try of the below codes, it works fine on my side:

```
package com.function;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;


public class Function {
    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        String query = req.getQueryParameters().get("name").toString();
        return req.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("hELLO " + query).build();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Please have a try, and let me know if you have some troubles.:)

Comment: I deleted everything and created an azure function using the maven command 'mvn generate' and surprisingly this worked. The Function.java got created in a similar way that you have mentioned here. But while I go and created using VS Code command, it creates problem. I have to dig deep. I will let you know the reason why one is working and one is not.

Comment: @SatyaPanigrahy Any update please let me know. I will update my answer.:)

Comment: @SatyaPanigrahy In fact, even use vs code to create a azure function is also need to run mvn generate because azure function tools dont have a java template, so we need to use mvn to generate a template.

Comment: Exactly, we have run maven generate template. Now I know that azure function tools don't have the java template. I will take a note of it for future. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @SatyaPanigrahy Hi, Satya. I have update your solution in my answer, can you [mark it as the answer of this question](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png)? This will help others who meet the similar question.:)